# Autoindent with minimal indentation

Tags: indentation, formatting

For some reason, Vim started to indent JavaScript in this crazy manner. I bet it's related to some settings in my syntax plugins, but I can't seem to figure out which ones are causing this behavior:

```
badFormattingWithLongLine.map(m =>
                               ...
                             )
```

Is there a way to force it to do minimal indentation for all files and filetypes as this Ruby-inspired flag-style is very annoying because I have to `dw` the whitespace manually for each line.

```
goodFormattingWithLongLine.map(m =>
  ...
)
```